# Deletebackward() Swift 3

Tags: swift3, emoticons

DeleteBackward() deletes only one character, is there any way to keep on deleting backwards ?

I am using emojiKeyboard and I have a delete emoticon. I detect the emoji being the delete emoticon and I call

```
if emoticon.isDelete{

        deleteBackward()
        return
    }
```

Update:

Steven's solution works on buttons but not on my UITextView. Will try and find out why. I have tried having the addGestureRecognizer in ViewWillAppear as well as ViewDidLoad.

Comment: When do you want the deleting to stop? For example when someone presses the delete emoticon should the whole text be deleted or should it stop deleting when user presses another key or emoticon?

Comment: I guess I want to replicate the regular keyboard delete button. So it should stop when users releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, didn't test but should do the trick.

```
fileprivate var timer = Timer()
fileprivate var textField = UITextField() //change to your field

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
    textField.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}


func longPress(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        longPressBegun(guesture)
    } else if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        //longPressStateChanged(guesture)
    } else if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        longPressEnded()
    } else if guesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.cancelled {
        longPressCancelled()
    }
}

func longPressBegun(_ guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(repeatAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func longPressEnded() {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func longPressCancelled() {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func repeatAction() {
    deleteBackward()
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steven, for some reason it's not being triggered on a UITextView